# Getting "NotImplementedError: Could not run 'torchvision::nms' with arguments from CUDA backend" despite having all necessary libraries and imports

Tags: python, pytorch, yolo

The full error:

```
NotImplementedError: Could not run 'torchvision::nms' with arguments from the 'CUDA' backend. This could be because the operator doesn't exist for this backend, or was omitted during the selective/custom build process (if using custom build). If you are a Facebook employee using PyTorch on mobile, please visit https://fburl.com/ptmfixes for possible resolutions. 'torchvision::nms' is only available for these backends: [CPU, QuantizedCPU, BackendSelect, Python, FuncTorchDynamicLayerBackMode, Functionalize, Named, Conjugate, Negative, ZeroTensor, ADInplaceOrView, AutogradOther, AutogradCPU, AutogradCUDA, AutogradXLA, AutogradMPS, AutogradXPU, AutogradHPU, AutogradLazy, Tracer, AutocastCPU, AutocastCUDA, FuncTorchBatched, FuncTorchVmapMode, Batched, VmapMode, FuncTorchGradWrapper, PythonTLSSnapshot, FuncTorchDynamicLayerFrontMode, PythonDispatcher].
```

I get this when attempting to train a YOLOv8 model on a Windows 11 machine, everything works for the first epoch then this occurs.

---

I also get this error immediately after the first epoch ends but I don't think it is relevant.

```
Error executing job with overrides: ['task=detect', 'mode=train', 'model=yolov8n.pt', 'data=custom.yaml', 'epochs=300', 'imgsz=160', 'workers=8', 'batch=4']
```

I was trying to train a YOLOv8 image detection model utilizing CUDA GPU.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This error occurs when you have Torch and Torchaudio for CUDA but not Torchvision for CUDA installed.

Uninstall Torch and Torchvision, I used pip:

```
pip uninstall torch torchvision
```

Then go [here](https://pytorch.org/) to install the proper versions of both using the nice interface. I got the following command:

```
pip install torch torchvision torchaudio --extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu116
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what causes this error but I know installing the proper version of torchvision and cuda didn't fix it. The way I solved is by uninstalling all of my packages and then reinstalling. Works just fine now. In hindsight, it may have been better to just update all my packages, but problem fixed none the less.

Answer (score 0):

This issue arises because you have installed a PyTorch version that is not compatible with the CUDA version (Compute Platform).
You can identify your CUDA version using the `nvidia-smi` command.

For example, if your CUDA version is 12, but you have installed a PyTorch version that is compatible with CUDA 12.1.
To resolve this, uninstall PyTorch and reinstall it to match your CUDA version (computer platform).
[Find the relevant PyTorch version](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/)

If your CUDA version is 12, and you cannot find a PyTorch version compatible with that, install a PyTorch version compatible with a CUDA version less than 12, such as 11.8. No issues will arise in this case.

Note that you cannot install a PyTorch version with a higher CUDA version than your current platform.

If you have installed the CPU version of PyTorch, this problem should not occur.